# MicrosoftGraphSdk for Java, InvalidAuthenticationToken, Invalid x5t claim

Tags: java, android, kotlin, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have successfully implemented login for personal account. Now I'm implementing login for business account and stuck with that error. IOS developer recommended me to use that scopes:

```
arrayOf(
    "api://<client-id>/Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "api://<client-id>/Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "api://<client-id>/Files.ReadWrite.All",
)
```

Which are working successfully for him but they are producing the following error for me:

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
    Error message: Invalid x5t claim.
```

Comment: Would you try pasting the token into https://jwt.ms/ to decode it and inspect the claims?